# Track no of logged in users as micrometer metric?

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have spring boot application and I want to track no of logged in users using a metric ( I am using `micrometer` ) . My idea was to track /login rest call which we have and increment a guage. However I don't have a solution to decrease metric ( gauge count ) with user expire. If i want to decrease gauge based on fixed time after i increase the gauge, how can i do that ? Also my service has two instance, therefore to be consistent i plan to use load
balancer session stickiness. With that i hope same user ( IP ) will land on same machine.

Following is my gauge

```
  AtomicInteger noOfLoggedInUsers = registry.gauge("logged.user.count", new AtomicInteger(0));
```

This is how i increment gauge

```
public int addUser(final String username) {
final String usernameVal = cache.get(username);
if (usernameVal == null) {
  cache.put(username, username);
  noOfLoggedInUsers.incrementAndGet();
}
return noOfLoggedInUsers.get();
```

}

I am using map to store unique users.
Also i want to know is there a better way i can do to track no of logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can look into:

1. Tomcat publishes a JMX counter called `activeSessions`: [see the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/monitoring.html)
   Micromeer has support for this, you can turn this on with `server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true` in case of Spring Boot.
2. You can schedule actions with a delay for the session expiry using [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/):
   `Mono.delay(ttl).subscribe(event -> noOfLoggedInUsers.decrementAndGet())`
   [Here's an example](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/resourceater/blob/5c28e3125d572484dca0e216641eb1474ff69001/src/main/java/resourceater/repository/ResourceRepository.java#L115)
3. Since you are also maintaining a Map (that I don't really understand), you can take a look at [Evictor](https://github.com/stoyanr/Evictor) that removes elements from a Concurrent Map after they expire (you might be able to reuse things from this project).